# Error in tabularx in ieee style

Tags: tabularx

I have a problem. Can you help me?

```
\begin{table*} ‎
 \caption{The parameters setting}‎
 \label{tab1}‎
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l*{10}{C}c@{}} ‎
  \toprule ‎
‎\textbf{algorithm}&\textbf{Population} & Generation & Crossover probability & Mutation rate & C1 & C2& weight & P$\alpha$ \\ 
 \midrule ‎
 %\addlinespace ‎
 ‎GABNL        & $10 or 50$ & $1000 or 5000$& $0.5$& $0.1$& $-$ &$-$& $-$ &$-$ \\‎
‎\cline{1-9}‎
‎PSOBNL & $10 or 50$ & $1000 or 5000$& $-$& $-$& $2.0$& $2.0$& $0.4-0.9$& $-$\\‎
‎\cline{1-9}‎
‎proposed  ‎algorithm & $10 or 50$ & $1000 or 5000$& $-$ &$-$ &$-$& $-$& $-$& $0.25$\\‎
\bottomrule ‎
\end{tabularx} ‎
\end{table*}‎‎
```

Comment: please provide an example that demonstrates the error. No one can run the fragment as posted without guessing required packages and the definition of the `C` column. Also if you have an error, please show the exact error from the log file, in a code section so that line endings are preserved.

Comment: `$1000 or 5000$` will put the whole expression in math mode and appear as _1000or5000_ you want `$1000$ or $5000$`

Comment: Please advise how the `C` column type is defined. And, why are you using `\cline` instead of `\cmidrule`?

Answer (score 7):

Some general comments:

- The code you posted is infested with invisible characters. *Get rid of them.*
- I can see no reason for typesetting all numbers in math mode.
- The table appears to contain 1 header column and 8 data columns. However, the `tabularx` environment is defined to contain 12 columns. Why? Where are the 3 "missing" columns? Are any columns, in fact, missing?
- Since you're using the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package, why do you employ `\cline`? `\addlinespace` would be a much better choice.

Implementing the changes implied by the preceding commas, making an educated guess as to how the `C` column type should be defined, assuming that the `IEEEtran` document class should be employed, and fixing several typos leads to the following compilable code. I hope it's close to what you need.

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\hspace{0pt}\Centering\arraybackslash}X} % just a guess
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\caption{Parameter Settings} \label{tab1}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{8}{C} @{}} % 9 columns total
\toprule
\bfseries Algorithm & \bfseries Population & Generation & 
   Crossover probability & Mutation rate & C1 & C2 &weight & $P\alpha$ \\
\midrule
‎GABNL             & 10 or 50 & 1000 or 5000 & 0.5 & 0.1 & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
\addlinespace
‎PSOBNL            & 10 or 50 & 1000 or 5000 & -- & -- & 2.0 & 2.0 & 0.4--0.9 & -- \\
\addlinespace
Proposed ‎algorithm& 10 or 50 & 1000 or 5000 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & 0.25\\
\bottomrule ‎
\end{tabularx} ‎
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One more comment: I really don't know why the first two cells in the header row are bolded. The table would look much better *without* the bold-facing.

Answer (score 4):

Mico has answered your question about `tabularx` but note that `tabularx` is designed to control the line breaking within cells. It was never intended for data tables such as this which have no line breaks within the entries.

The only effect of forcing the table to be `\textwidth` wide is excessive space between the text in the entries, so making the table harder to read.

Here is the same data presented using a standard `tabular`, allowing the cells to be set at their natural width.

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{Parameter Settings} \label{tab1}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{8}{c} @{}} % 9 columns total
\toprule
\bfseries Algorithm & \bfseries Population & Generation & 
   Crossover probability & Mutation rate & C1 & C2 &weight & $P\alpha$ \\
\midrule
‎GABNL             & 10 or 50 & 1000 or 5000 & 0.5 & 0.1 & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
\addlinespace
‎PSOBNL            & 10 or 50 & 1000 or 5000 & -- & -- & 2.0 & 2.0 & 0.4--0.9 & -- \\
\addlinespace
Proposed ‎algorithm& 10 or 50 & 1000 or 5000 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & 0.25\\
\bottomrule ‎
\end{tabular} ‎

X\dotfill \textit{to show the text width} \dotfill X
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico sorry:-) Ohh looks like I hadn't returned the favour, will fix...